# Seperating a dataframe into subsets based on a sorted columns values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe and the columns are as follows

`['time_of_incident', 'vendor_tech', 'incident_closed']`

I have the data frame sorted by the vendor_tech alphabetically. I want to split this large dataframe. Size of about 18,000 entries into multiple dataframes based on the value in `vendor_tech`

I have tried many solutions and can't seem to find anything like this on StackOverflow. I've tried many inefficient and convoluted solutions with no luck.

My main problem is when I use `.itertuple()` and iterate over the objects I am not able to then add those objects to another DataFrame

Comment: `split = {name: df for name, df in your_big_dataframe.groupby("vendor_tech")}`

Comment: can you a small working sample of the data-frame or file?  I am thinking you can create a column that categorizes the data in as many buckets as you want, than use group by i.e. [group for name, group in df.groupby('column to split the df by')] than run a loop to the results to new dataframes.

Comment: @CJR Worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

```
# try this

df
     time_of_incident       vendor_tech Incident_closed
0   1970-04-05 17:23:44.460 a           yes
1   1994-11-25 17:23:44.460 a           no
2   1980-02-12 17:23:44.460 a           no
3   1978-06-22 17:23:44.460 b           yes
4   1990-10-17 17:23:44.460 b           yes
5   1960-05-27 17:23:44.460 b           yes
6   1980-02-12 17:23:44.460 c           no
```

## Group your data by 'vendor tech'

```
mini_df = [(name,group) for name,group in df.groupby('vendor_tech')]
```

## create a dictionary of dataframes

```
mini_list = list(df['vendor_tech'].unique())
mini_dict ={}
for i in range(len(mini_df)):
    label = mini_list.pop(0)
    mini_dict['df_'+str(label)] = pd.DataFrame(mini_df[i][1], columns=df.columns)
```

## call each dataframe (which as unique based on 'vendor tech')

```
df_a
time_of_incident            vendor_tech Incident_closed
0   1970-04-05 17:23:44.460 a           yes
1   1994-11-25 17:23:44.460 a           no
2   1980-02-12 17:23:44.460 a           no

df_b
    time_of_incident        vendor_tech Incident_closed
3   1978-06-22 17:23:44.460 b           yes
4   1990-10-17 17:23:44.460 b           yes
5   1960-05-27 17:23:44.460 b           yes
```

## you can than save each df to a different file if you want

[image]